# Update not working as required

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am having issue with update in table. In my below I have updating flag of column `userdeleted`, I also want to change the value of that row with `CurrentTimestamp` value but after I placed a one more condition in `SET`, my all rows value gets updated to current timestamp.

```
UPDATE dpuserapplication t1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN temp_userapplication t2
ON t1.userName = t2.userName
AND t1.ApplicationName = t2.ApplicationName
AND t1.groupName = t2.groupName
SET t1.userDeleted = CASE WHEN t2.ID IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
t1.CreatedDate = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Comment: i only want to updated that row whose column userdeleted set to 0 not all the rows.

Answer (score 0):

That happens because of the `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, that returns all rows of `dpuserapplication` unless you specify a `WHERE` clause. As you don't specify any condition for modifying the timestamp, it gets modified on each row.

Try adding a condition:

```
UPDATE dpuserapplication t1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN temp_userapplication t2
                    ON t1.username = t2.username
                       AND t1.applicationname = t2.applicationname
                       AND t1.groupname = t2.groupname
SET    t1.userdeleted = CASE
                          WHEN t2.id IS NULL THEN 1
                          ELSE 0
                        END,
       t1.createddate = CASE
                          WHEN t2.id IS NOT NULL THEN CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
                          ELSE t1.createddate
                        END;
```

See [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3a21d/1).

After your comment, if you want to update only rows where `userdeleted` was set to 1 and is now set to 0:

```
UPDATE dpuserapplication t1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN temp_userapplication t2
                    ON t1.username = t2.username
                       AND t1.applicationname = t2.applicationname
                       AND t1.groupname = t2.groupname
SET    t1.userdeleted = CASE
                          WHEN t2.id IS NULL THEN 1
                          ELSE 0
                        END,
       t1.createddate = CASE
                          WHEN t2.id IS NOT NULL AND t1.userdeleted = 1 THEN CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
                          ELSE t1.createddate
                        END;
```

See [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/69efb/1).

In this fiddle :

- u1 has userdeleted = 1, but fits the conditions. Its status is changed to 0, and the date is updated.
- u2 has userdeleted = 0, and fits the conditions. Its status is set to 0 (no change), but the date is not updated.
- u3 doesn't fit the conditions, nothing happens.

Comment: can we put case condition like as used for UserDeleted in SET, I am new to mysql and dont have much knowledge on this

Comment: Yes, AFAIK there's no problem with that.

Comment: but this is not working.. all rows gets same timestamp afte running this script    UPDATE dpuserapplication t1 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN temp_userapplication t2
    ON t1.userName = t2.userName
AND t1.ApplicationName = t2.ApplicationName
AND t1.groupName = t2.groupName
SET t1.userDeleted = CASE WHEN t2.ID IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
    t1.CreatedDate = CASE WHEN t2.ID IS NULL THEN CURRENT_TIMESTAMP         END;

Comment: Oops, forgot the `ELSE` clause. Fixed.

Comment: Will it only update that row whose status get changes from userdeleted 1 to 0

Comment: No, it will do want you asked for, that is update `CreatedDate` rows in `dpuserapplication`  that have their equivalent in `temp_userapplication`, no matter previous `userdeleted` value. If you want to update only those which change from 1 to 0, there's another condition to add.

Comment: actually what my previous update statement was doing: if a rows in temp_userapplication already exist in dpuserapplication then inspite of creating a new rows it was changing the userdeleted to 0, but when this was happening my created date was not changing and showing old date.

Comment: sorry but this query didnt work it still updated rows who has userdeleted 0

Comment: I quote your comment under your question : "i only want to updated that row whose column userdeleted set to 0 not all the rows". Eventually, you'll have to specify EXACTLY what you want in your question, it's getting really unclear.

Comment: if a userdeleted of a row gets changed from 1 to 0 then for that row column createddate value gets changed to current timestamp not all the other rows. Now with this query if a changed a userdeleted from 1 to 0 then for all rows whose userdeleted is already 0 also gets changes to current timestamp